# Does PowerCLI have PowerShell Profiles?

Tags: vmware-esxi, powercli

[Powershell has profiles](https://superuser.com/questions/1090141/does-powershell-have-any-sort-of-bashrc-equivalent) that you can use to load functions you've written when your shell loads up.  Does PowerCLI have a similar functionality?

Answer (score 0):

PowerCLI is nothing less than a powershell console that is started with a ps1 script which initializes the Powershell VMWare Commandlets.

So i would say you could do anything with this powerCLI that you can do with the powerShell. You could even add lines into the loaded ps1 file - which on my Server is located at `%ProgramFiles(x86)\VMware\Infrastructure\vSphere PowerCLI\Scripts\Initialize-PowerCLIEnvironment.ps1`.